# to prove that string s$2$ is rotation of string s$1$ if s$1$+c=c+s$2$ where c is another string

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have two strings S$1$ and  S$2$  AND both are of same size n and both consists of first k letters of English alphabet .If there exists another string C such that

```
                S1+C=C+S2
```

then how can we prove that string s$2$ is a rotation of string s$1$?
Here + means concatenation of strings .